# Scala type mismatch how to convert Iterable[Double] to Double

Tags: scala, spotify-scio

I am trying to modify [this](https://github.com/spotify/scio/blob/main/scio-examples/src/main/scala/com/spotify/scio/examples/extra/TypedBigQueryTornadoes.scala) example as follows:

```
@BigQueryType.fromQuery("SELECT weight_pounds FROM [bigquery-public-data:samples.natality]")
  class Row

@BigQueryType.toTable
  case class Result(weight_pounds: Double)

sc.typedBigQuery[Row]()
      .map(r => r.weight_pounds.getOrElse(0.0)) // return 0 if weight_pounds is None
      .top(100)
      .map(x => Result(x))
      // Convert elements from Result to TableRow and save output to BigQuery.
      .saveAsTypedBigQueryTable(
        Table.Spec(args("output")),
        writeDisposition = WRITE_TRUNCATE,
        createDisposition = CREATE_IF_NEEDED
      )
```

Above gives me following error:

```
[error] /Users/me/scio/scio-examples/src/main/scala/com/spotify/scio/examples/foo.scala:66:24: type mismatch;
[error]  found   : Iterable[Double]
[error]  required: Double
[error]       .map(x => Result(x))
[error]                        ^
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: try `flatMap` instead of `map`. It seems like the return type of `top` is `SCollection[Iterable[T]]` so `map` doesn't reach inside the `Iterable`

Comment: You probably want something like `.top(100).flatMap(doubles => doubles.map(Result.apply))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick is to add a `flatMap(x => x)` right after `top(100)`

Comment: `flatMap(identity)` should be `flatten`

Comment: thanks for the tip. verified that `.flatten` (without parentheses) also works.